# @Transactional annotation java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transaction must be running

Tags: jta, transactional, java-ee-7

I am using JavaEE7 and container managed transactions in my Project. Although i have @Transactional annotation on method, i am getting "Transaction must be running" exception.
Code seems as following:

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
public void myMethod(Project project) {

    final ObjectIdentity objectId = new ObjectIdentityImpl(project);
    final Sid sid = new PrincipalSid(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    final Permission p = BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION;
    MutableAcl acl = null;
    try {
        List<Sid> sids = new ArrayList<>();
        sids.add(sid);
        acl = (MutableAcl) aclService.readAclById(objectId, sids);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        acl = ((MutableAclService) aclService).createAcl(objectId); // This line causes exception
    }

    acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), p, sid, true);
    aclService.updateAcl(acl);
}
```

What is missing in this code, that transaction does not begin?

Kind regards,

Bilal

Comment: I think transaction begins but spring is not aware. There is a method to register transaction in TransactionSynchronizationManager.`TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(TransactionSynchronization synchronization)`. I think the transaction is not registered.

Answer (score 4):

A method annotated with `Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY` requires an already running transaction. It means that when the method invocation begins a transaction MUST be already started. You do that by starting transaction in another method that invokes your method annotated with `Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY`.

If you want to start a NEW transaction when there is no transaction currently running you must set the transaction type to `Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED` (new transaction will be started if no transaction is already runnig) or `Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW` (new transaction will be started no matter what) - it depends on your needs. The `Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED` type is the default transaction type in CDI so actually you can go with just `@Transactional` without specifying any type.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html for more information